# Why is the estimated monthly income state-dependent on CNNMoney's annuity calculator?

Tags: united-states, calculation, annuity

Why is the estimated monthly income state-dependent on [CNNMoney's annuity calculator](http://money.cnn.com/tools/annuities/)?

Example:  CA (376 USD) vs. IL (385 USD)

[image]

> Estimated monthly income: $376

[image]

> Estimated monthly income: $385

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- http://qr.ae/TbckiY
- https://redd.it/704tys

Comment: Different state tax rates.

Comment: @HartCO Is  CNNMoney's annuity calculator's estimated monthly income post-tax?

Comment: I should have put a question mark on there, was a guess. I compared results for several states that don't have income tax and the results varied, so that's not it.

Comment: @HartCO Thanks for the clarification. Same here, after trying a few states I also do not think income tax explains the difference  (e.g., IL has more income tax than WA, but the life annuity is the same).

Answer (score 4):

Obviously you'd have to ask who wrote it to be 100% certain, but my guess is since an annuity pays for life, it will estimate the payments based on life expectancy, which varies from state to state (and by gender)

Answer (score 1):

Another hypothesis explaining the estimated monthly income state-dependent on CNNMoney's annuity calculator: income annuities incur a premium tax in certain states.

Two other calculators mention this:

http://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/investing/accounts_products/investment/annuities/income_annuity/fixed_income_annuity_calculator :

[image]

https://gie.fidelity.com/estimator/gie/ownerinfo:

[image]

FYI:

- [Why do some states tax annuity premiums?](https://www.bogleheads.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=102443) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170914070411/https://www.bogleheads.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=102443))
- [Are You Located in a State with Good Annuities?](https://annuityguys.org/are-you-located-in-a-state-with-good-annuities/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170914070445/https://annuityguys.org/are-you-located-in-a-state-with-good-annuities/))